# Query only data during current month

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, ssms

I have a simple SQL query as below:

```
select   ProjectNo,
         CostCat,
         SummaryCostCat,
         CreditorEmployeeName,
         UnitCost,
         TotalCost,
         TransactionDate
from dbo.NGPCostPosition
```

This gives me a selection of data as below:

[image]

What I would like to do is create a new column in my data called 'CurrentValue' that would be a calculation of every TotalCost value based on the Transaction Date being in the current month.

Ideally this would change as I changed into a new month going forwards.

An example of this is the below image:-

[image]

where CurrentValue represents the Current Months figures.

Comment: Your first image of data does not even match the desired result in the second image. Can you clarify what you are trying to do?  Please edit the question with your table structures, sample data and desired result as well as any queries you are currently using.

Comment: sorry I have updated the whole question to try and make it clearer for what i am trying to do

Answer (score 13):

This will use an index, unlike "tricks" to convert a datetime to string and then back to date, or using `DATEPART` against your columns.

```
WHERE TransactionDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
AND TransactionDate < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())+1, 0);
```

Tidier?

```
DECLARE @ms SMALLDATETIME, @me SMALLDATETIME;
SET @ms = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0);
SET @me = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @ms);

SELECT
...
WHERE TransactionDate >= @ms AND TransactionDate < @me;
```

With the ever-changing requirements, how about using the @ms/@me variables shown above, and then:

```
CurrentValue = CASE 
  WHEN TransactionDate >= @ms AND TransactionDate < @me
  THEN TotalCost END
```

Also note that `TransactionDate` should not be in your grouping column if you are going to perform some kind of aggregate. We can write your whole query if you show us what result you actually want - the column list and grouping you had didn't really make sense on first glance, so based on your actual question I obscured those so we can focus on the actual `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I have updated my original qst to include an example of what i am trying to achieve

Comment: @user1086159 Sorry, I still do not follow what you're doing. The output doesn't match any of the input, so I don't know if you are aggregating or not, what you mean by "current month" if you are listing individual days, etc.

Comment: sorry I have updated the whole question to try and make it clearer for what i am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DATEPART function to check month and year:

```
WHERE DATEPART(month, GETDATE()) = DATEPART(month, Date)) 
AND (DATEPART(year, GETDATE()) = DATEPART(year, Date)
```

Comment: Expensive, won't use an index.

Answer (score 0):

```
select   ProjectNo,
         CostCat,
         SummaryCostCat,
         CreditorEmployeeName,
         UnitCost,
         TotalCost,
         TransactionDate,
         CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, TransactionDate) = DATEPART(month, GETDATE()) AND
                   DATEPART(year, TransactionDate) = DATEPART(year, GETDATE()) THEN
                     TotalCost
               ELSE NULL
          END AS CurrentValue
from dbo.NGPCostPosition
```